# Visualization of the relationship between Conjugacy Classes and Centraliser

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I've recently come across a theorem in my abstract algebra course which states that

for a finite group $G$ and for any $a\in G$

$|\text{cl}(a)|=[G:C(a)]$ where $\text{cl}(a)$ is the conjugacy class of $a$ and $C(a)$ is the centraliser pf $a$. That means the number of elements in $\text{cl}(a)$ is the same as the number of left or right cosets of $C(a)$ in $G.$

There is a nice proof given in my book, but I like to visualize all such abstract things. So my thought is :

If $g\in C(a)$ then  for those $g\in G$ , $gag^{-1}=a$.

If $g\not\in C(a)$ then  for those $g\in G$ , $gag^{-1}\ne a$. In this case $g$ is taken from a coset of $C(a)$.

Now the question is from which coset should $g$ be taken in order to have $gag^{-1}\ne a$?

The conjugacy class of $a$ measures how much commutativeness or non-commutativeness property the element $a$ has.

$C(a)$ is a collection of those elements which commute with $a.$ If $x C(a)$ be some left coset of $C(a)$ in $G$ then the non-commutative behaviour of all elements in  $x C(a)$ with the element $a$ are the same.

All the elements of $xC(a)$ have the same non-commutative structure, so for all $h\in xC(a),$ the conjugates of $a$ by $h$ give the same result i.e. $\forall h\in xC(a),hah^{-1}=\text{a fixed element in G.}$

Here is a short proof: if $g_{1}\in C(a)$ then $xg_{1}\in xC(a)$ so that $(xg_{1})a(xg_{1})^{-1}=x(g_{1}ag_{1}^{-1})x^{-1}=xax^{-1}$ which is the same for all $g_{1}x\in C(a).$

Hence, for each left coset $xC(a)$ there corresponds exactly one member of the conjugacy class $\text{cl}(a)$. There are $[G:C(a)]$ distinct left cosets of $C(a)$ in $G,$ so $|\text{cl}(a)|=[G:C(a)]$ .

My question is my arguments correct? And if not please enlighten me. Or are there any better way for visualization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your prove it is right. There is another approach to the problem:

You can define the map $\pi: G\to cl(a)$ such that for each $g\in G$ you have that

$\pi(g)=gag^{-1}$

Now by first fundamental theorem you have that

$G/\sim \cong cl(a)$

Where the relation $\sim$ is the following  relation induced by the map $\pi$ on $G$:

$c\sim b$ if and only if $\pi(c)=\pi(b)$

We want prove that the relation $\sim$ is equivalent to the relation induced by $C(a)$ on $G$ , i.e.

$c\sim b$ if and only if $c^{-1}b\in C(a)$

If we prove this fact we will have that

$G/\sim =G/C(a)$

$\rightarrow$ :

If $c\sim b$ then $cac^{-1}=bab^{-1}$

then

$a(c^{-1}b)=c^{-1}(cac^{-1})b=c^{-1}(bab^{-1})b=(c^{-1}b )a$

so  $a(c^{-1}b)= (c^{-1}b )a$ that means $c^{-1}b\in C(a)$

$\leftarrow$ :

If $c^{-1}b\in C(a)$ then

$\pi(c)=cac^{-1}=c(ac^{-1}b)b^{-1}=c(c^{-1}ba)b^{-1}=$

$=bab^{-1}=\pi(b)$

so

$c\sim b$

We have proved that

$G/C(a)=G/\sim \cong cl(a)$

So you have that

$|cl(a)|=[G: C(a)]$

Comment: Thank you for answering :)